# Split Name Column which can contain Multiple Names and no delimiter into Person 1 and Person 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parsing, split

How do I split a string which can contain 2 names into Person1 and Person2 ?  There is no delimiter between the names, there is not always a second person for each row and not necessarily a middle initial/name for either first or second person and only sometimes the second name will be separated with an “AND”
    Examples of Names are as follows

- JANE MIDDLETON John MIDDLETON
- SUE FRACARO BOB FRACARO
- TONY FRENCH
- JOHN  EDUARDO OCHOA AND JANE ADRIANA OCHOA
- TONY JOHN CARPENTER TONYA CARPENTER

**Desired Output Design**

- Person 1 First Name
- Person 1 Middle Name
- Person 1 Last Name
- Person 2 First Name
- Person 2 Middle Name
- Person 2 Last Name

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running? (`SELECT @@VERSION`)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP3

Comment: Unfortunately this is VERY common scenario which is a direct result of poor design. Your best option is to get professional data architect and redesign your database! If this is how one table designed then I am pretty sure your entire database should be re-design and maybe the system in general.

Comment: To clarify, I did not down-voted your question and I think that there is no bad questions but only bad approach of asking a question and bad responses. First case the OP can fix and second option is part of getting free support. In any case, I am against the ability of down-vote in forums in general

Comment: Just to repeat what Ronen said, you need to provide the exact rules for how to split the string and only then can we assist building a query. I suspect you will not be able to create rules that will be accurate 100% of the time. For example, your last example has 5 words, what rule would we use to know that the first 3 apply to person 1 and the last 2 apply to person 2? It could just as easy be the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function for splitting string values in question from some table column:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_Splittemp]
        (
          @text VARCHAR(8000)
        , @delimiter VARCHAR(20) = ' '
        )
        RETURNS @String TABLE
            (
                  Position INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
                , StringValue VARCHAR(8000)
            )
        AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @index INT
            SET @index = -1
            WHILE (LEN(@text) >0)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @text)
                            IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0)
                                BEGIN
                                    INSERT INTO @string VALUES (@text)
                                    BREAK
                                END
                            IF (@index > 1)
                                BEGIN
                                    INSERT INTO @String VALUES (LEFT(@text, (@index-1)))
                                    SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text)-@index))
                                END
                            ELSE
                                    SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text)-@index))
                                END
                        RETURN
                    END
    GO
```

---

Splitting, cleaning and assigning to respective name_columns:

```
CREATE TABLE #t0 (rid INT IDENTITY, rawnames VARCHAR(8000));
GO

INSERT INTO #t0 VALUES ('JANE MIDDLETON John MIDDLETON'),
('SUE FRACARO BOB FRACARO'),
('TONY FRENCH'),
('JOHN EDUARDO OCHOA AND JANE ADRIANA OCHOA'),
('TONY JOHN CARPENTER TONYA CARPENTER');
GO

SELECT n.rid, n.rawnames, fn.StringValue AS Names, 
COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY rawnames) AS wordcount,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fn.stringvalue,rawnames ORDER BY fn.stringvalue) AS LastNameids,
fn.Position
INTO #t1
FROM #t0 n
cross apply dbo.Fn_Splittemp(n.rawnames, ' ') AS fn
GO

SELECT rid, rawnames, Position AS Pid, 
PersonName, LastName INTO #t2
FROM
(SELECT t.rid, t.rawnames, t.names AS Lastname, LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(f.StringValue,'and',''))) AS PersonName, f.Position
FROM
    (SELECT replace(sqa.rawnames,sqa.Names,sqa.Names+',') AS delimstr , sqa.* 
        FROM #t1 sqa
        WHERE wordcount<=3 AND position = (SELECT MAX(position) from #t1 crq where crq.rid = sqa.rid)
    )t
cross apply dbo.Fn_Splittemp(delimstr,',') f
UNION ALL
SELECT b.rid, b.rawnames, b.Names AS Lastname, LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(f.StringValue,'and',''))) AS PersonName, f.Position
FROM 
(SELECT replace(rawnames,names,names+',') AS delimstr, *
FROM #t1 
WHERE wordcount>3 AND LastNameids>1)b
cross apply dbo.Fn_Splittemp(delimstr,',') f
)sqt
GO

SELECT * INTO #t3 FROM #t2 cross apply dbo.Fn_Splittemp(personname, ' ');
GO

SELECT t.rawnames, fina.Firstname, fina.MiddleName, fina.LastName
FROM #t0 t
JOIN (
SELECT rid, pid, [1] AS Firstname, NULL AS MiddleName, [2] AS LastName 
FROM
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT rid, pid, position, stringvalue, 
COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY rid, pid) AS cnt FROM #t3)a
WHERE a.cnt <=2)apiv
PIVOT
(MAX(stringvalue)
    FOR position IN ([1],[2])
    )piva
UNION ALL
SELECT rid, pid, [1] AS Firstname, [2] AS MiddleName, [3] AS LastName
FROM
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT rid, pid, position, stringvalue, 
COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY rid, pid) AS cnt FROM #t3)a
WHERE a.cnt >2)apiv
PIVOT
(MAX(stringvalue)
    FOR position IN ([1],[2],[3])
    )piva
)fina
ON fina.rid = t.rid;
```

Comment: Aside: There are plenty of references for better ways to split strings, e.g. [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function).

Comment: The solution KGRed has provided seems to work with the exception if a name has a middle initial  or middle name such as 'John A Doe' so I'm not sure why its not working when there is a middle initial.

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake.
the position of lastname was hardcoded to 2  for names with wordcount <3
it should be as below:

`WHERE wordcount<=3 AND position = (SELECT MAX(position) from #t1 crq where crq.rid = sqa.rid)`

Comment: thank you!  Your solution worked for most of my data (88K records) with a few tweaks to fit my data.  I will manually parse out the records it didn't work on.